# JS returns [object objec] for req.body, which is undefined unless page refreshed

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm following some tutorials on Single Page TodoList App, and ran into a issue when trying to create new Todos.
This TODO list app is supposed to have a input place where you type in your todo, then hit enter, then the newly added todo should show up at the end of your list, without needing to refresh the page.

My issue is that, whenever i add new todo then hit enter, it shows up as "undefined", but after I refresh the page, it will show up as expected.

I think the issue is in the createTodo function. When I console.log(req.body), instead of ({name: "value"}), I get a [object object]. And for the res.json(newTodo), nothing is returned, while it's supposed to return the newTodo.

```
exports.createTodo = function(req, res){
  db.Todo.create(req.body)
  .then(function(newTodo){
      res.status(201).json(newTodo);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
      res.send(err);
  })
}
```

I double checked that I have installed body-parser and required and used it as documented:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var todoRoutes = require("./routes/todos");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("index.html");
});
```

Could someone please help me out?
thank you!

Comment: Add a `console.log(err)` to your `.catch()` function. It's possible that these are in the wrong order, as some APIs do `err, response` instead of `response, err`

Comment: Thank you! I ran the code again and magically it worked now!!

Comment: lol - it didn't magically work, but some API's provide callback arguments with the error first, thenthe successful data, while other API's provide the callback function the successful data first, then the error. Just review the API docs carefully.